# why sublimetext2 crashes when using SFTP in Windows 7

Tags: plugins, windows-7, sublimetext2, sftp

SublimeText2 crashed when using SFTP to save on Windows 7

Note: Other function work well.

I have also tried uninstall it and install it again twice, but not working.

thank you!

Comment: This is certainly not enough information about your problem to allow anyone to help you.

Comment: @user2709853 Please provide details for you Windows 7, is it 32Bit or 64Bit? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this [`link`](https://coderwall.com/p/52p2xa) and follow instruction,

here given step by step configuration for the same, this should do the best

Let me know if its working or not,

If not please provide which type of Windows 7 is there, there were some issues with sublime 2 in x64 system.